# React Component Animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The transition works but when I have visibility: hidden, I get excess whitespace to the right of the viewport. If I set display: none, I lose the transition effect. Any ideas how to do this w/ react, vanilla js or css? I prefer not to use a third party library (other than react).

https://codepen.io/nosaka/pen/LjRLgG

JS

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {hidden: true};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      hidden: !prevState.hidden
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.hidden ? 'Show' : 'Hide'}
      </button>
      <div className={"modal-overlay " + (this.state.hidden ? "hidden" : "open")} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <div className="modal">
          Modal
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Modal />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

CSS

```
.modal-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: -40vw;
  z-index: 20;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease .5s;
  &.open {
    right: 0px;
  }
}

.modal {
  box-shadow: -1px 4px 5px 1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  background-color: #fefefe;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  padding-left: none;
  padding-right: none;
  cursor: auto;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: im not sure i see what you mean by the excess whitespace

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're animating the CSS property but the component, and therefore the DOM element are still in the DOM flow, hence the horizontal scroll bar is visible.

I'd recommend you to use React Transition Group in order to remove the component and do it the *React way*. Here's a simple example of using RTG to toggle a component:

https://codesandbox.io/s/DkEmExJG6